# How do you run python scripts from other script and have their root in my root?

Tags: python, import, global-variables, module

I have a module "B", I want to run it from a script "C", and I want to call global variables in "B", as they were in the "C" root. Another problem is if I imported `sys` in "B" when I run "C" it doesn't see `sys`

`# NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined #`

What shall I do?

Comment: Looks quite hacky. May be if you give us a real example we will have ideas about how to do it in right way?

Comment: In general, you don't want to do that. Modules are great for keeping objects in a separate namespace from your main program.

Answer (score 5):

When you import a module `B` (like `import B`), every line in `B` will be interpreted.  I assume this is what you mean when you say you want to run it.  To reference members in `B`'s namespace, you can get them like:

`B.something_defined_in_B`.

If you wish to use `sys` explicitly in `C`, you will need to import it within `C` as well.

Answer (score 1):

is it in your PYTHON_PATH?

if not, in script C's **init**.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/PATH/TO/MODULE/B')
```

then, in module C

```
from B import *
something_defined_in_B()
```